# Incorrect data returned by Calendar API

Tags: java, calendar, dayofweek, java.util.calendar

In our business requirement we are supposed to find out the first day of the week.

Since the client is `European` so I used following code to get it.

But, issue is when I run this code I am getting `2` as the answer where as I am expecting `1`.

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeZone eu = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"); 
        Locale de = Locale.forLanguageTag("de"); 
        int firstDayOfWeek = Calendar.getInstance(eu, de).getFirstDayOfWeek(); 
        System.out.println(firstDayOfWeek);
    }
}
```

Can some one help me understand this behavior.

Comment: Why are you expecting 1? isn't MONDAY the first day of the week in Europe? According to Javadoc, it is at least for France: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getFirstDayOfWeek()

Comment: Yes Monday is first day of week in Europe, hence we expect answer to be 1

Comment: `getFirstDayOfWeek` is `Locale` dependent.

Comment: Monday is 2. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.MONDAY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getFirstDayOfWeek()):

> Gets what the first day of the week is; e.g., SUNDAY in the U.S., MONDAY in France.

and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.MONDAY):

> public static final int   MONDAY  2

This shows that the return value depends on the locale.

If we print this:

```
System.out.println(firstDayOfWeek == Calendar.MONDAY);
```

We'll see `true`. This means that the first day of week is indeed Monday. It's just that you thought Monday is encoded by 1. In fact, Sunday is encoded as 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Locale de = Locale.forLanguageTag("de");
    WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(de);
    DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = wf.getFirstDayOfWeek();
    System.out.println(firstDayOfWeek);
```

This prints:

> MONDAY

Don’t use the confusing old `Calendar` class. You got 2 as the first day of the week. But weren’t you supposed to get 1? Or 0? How are days of the week numbered? Forget about numbers, use the `DayOfWeek` enum from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.

For prettier output use `DayOfWeek.getDisplayName` or a `DateTimeFormatter`. If you do need a number, use `DayOfWeek.getValue`:

```
    System.out.println(firstDayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, de));
    System.out.println(firstDayOfWeek.getValue());
```

Output is:

```
Montag
1
```

PS Also don’t use `TimeZone` and the other long outdated date and time classes. `java.time` is so much nicer to work with. This fact shows nicely in this example, but its typical, certainly no coincidence.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.MONDAY), MONDAY's valus is 2.